# Is there a placeholder for Xamarin Forms 3.6 Datepicker with material visual?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using the Xamarin Forms 3.6 material visual.  I have a contentpage with both Entry and DatePicker controls.  Entry renders a placeholder great - however, a datepicker does not appear to have an option for a placeholder/title/label.

Looking to see if anyone else has come across this?  Will this be a custom renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create `CustomRenderer` I'm afraid. But there is nothing bad with it, there is a [good guide](http://venkyxamarin.blogspot.com/2018/04/datepicker-placeholder-border-style.html) of how to solve this sort of problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up just "wrapping" the DatePicker (or TimePicker) with a Frame and Grid, and created my own label.  Then played with margins and background colors to get it to look 99% like a text entry with the floating label.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it following Klein's advice:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="30, 35">
    <DatePicker Date="{Binding DateTo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0, -35, 0, 0"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                WidthRequest="200"
                Format="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                TextTransform="Uppercase"
                FontSize="Body" />
     <Label Text="To" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="12, 10, 0, 0"
            Style="{StaticResource LabelCaption}" />
 </Grid>
```

Output:

[image: DatePicker Placeholder in Xamarin Forms]